# What does the Vedas and Upanishads say about Ayam and Atma?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

What does the Vedas and Upanishads say about the nature of Ayam and Atma and how are they different from Purusha and Prakriti?

Comment: Ayam is just the Sanskrit word for "this".  Are you referring to the quote "Ayam Atma Brahma" from the Mandukya Upanishad?  It just means "This soul is Brahman."

Comment: @Keshav Is there any other verses in the Vedas/Upanishads where 'Ayam' is used?

Comment: Like I said, "Ayam" is just the Sanskrit word for "this".  So of course lots of texts would contain the word "this" in them.  "Ayam" is simply not the interesting word in the phrase "Ayam Atma Brahma".  The interesting part is the (seeming) equating of Atma and Brahman.  The word Ayam just indicates that we're talking about "this atma", as opposed to some other atma.